# Segmentation fault in C dynamic array

Tags: c, struct

I'm getting values from mysql database, I want to organize it with each row returned.  here's my struct(example only):

```
typedef struct 
{
    char* name;
    char* etc;
    int state;

} person;
```

and the MySql:

```
MYSQL * con;
mysql_connect(&con); //connect to mysql database and set handle to con variable.
MYSQL_ROW row;
MYSQL_RES * result;
int num_fields, i;
mysql_query(con, "select name,etc,state from db.tbl");
result = mysql_store_result (con);
num_fields = mysql_num_fields (result);
person tempdata;
person personlist[num_fields * sizeof(person)]; //the size if the problem, I believe... 
while((row = mysql_fetch_row (result))) {
   tempdata.name = row[0];
   tempdata.etc  = row[1];
   tenpdata.state = atoi(row[2]);
   personlist[i++] = tempdata;  // the error line
}

mysql_free_result (result);
mysql_close (con);
```

but it returns `Segmentation fault` how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a debugger (e.g. gdb) and try to locate the line in which the segmentation fault happens.

Comment: Where does the segmentation fault happen? We cannot replicate your entire test setup, so any and all information you can provide is only going to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare an array of structures, you specify its size as number of elements. Number of persons in your case. Declare it without `sizeof(person)`: `person personlist[num_fields];`.

You also use variable `i` without being initialized. Change its declaration to `int num_fields, i = 0;`.

And note that `tempdata.name = row[0];` makes `name` point to the same data as `row[0]` points to. You probably want to allocate memory for `name` and copy `row[0]` into it (check unwinds answer).

Answer (score 5):

You are not copying the strings. You are just storing pointers which are probably rendered invalid as soon as the MySQL results are freed.

You need to use `strdup()` or equivalent to create local copies of the strings, now you're just storing pointers into MySQL's data.

If you don't have it, here's a quick and dirty replacement:

```
char * my_strdup(const char *string)
{
  if(string != NULL)
  {
    const size_t slen = strlen(string);
    char *out = malloc(slen + 1);
    if(out != NULL)
    {
      strcpy(out, string);
      return out;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Note that it's not named `strdup()`, since that's a reserved name.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num_fields, i;//Then you have not set a initial value to the variable i.
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_num_fields` returns the number of columns in your result set. `sizeof(person)` will be 12 or so on a 32-bit system. `i` is not initialised.

You need `i` to start at zero, and you want enough storage for your rows, not 12 times the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the string-copying issue mentioned previously:

```
person personlist[mysql_num_rows(result)];
```

You need enough storage for the number of rows, not the number of fields.